# Optimization function across multiple factors

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I am trying to identify the appropriate thresholds for two activities which generate the greatest success rate.

Listed below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. For each location I am trying to identify the thresholds to use for activities 1 & 2, so that if either criteria is met then we would guess 'yes' (1). I then need to make sure that we are guessing 'yes' for only a certain percentage of the total volume for each location, and that we are maximizing our accuracy (our guess of yes = 'outcome' of 1).

```
location <- c(1,2,3)    
testFile <- data.frame(location = rep.int(location, 20),
                          activity1 = round(rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 3)),
                          activity2 = round(rnorm(20, mean = 20, sd = 3)),
                          outcome = rbinom(20,1,0.5)
                       )
    set.seed(145)
    act_1_thresholds <- seq(7,12,1)
    act_2_thresholds <- seq(19,24,1)
```

I was able to accomplish this by creating a table that contains all of the possible unique combinations of thresholds for activities 1 & 2, and then merging it with each observation within the sample data set. However, with ~200 locations in the actual data set, each of which with thousands of observations I quickly ran of out of space.

I would like to create a function that takes the location id, set of possible thresholds for activity 1, and also for activity 2, and then calculates how often we would have guessed yes (i.e. the values in 'activity1' or 'activity2' exceed their respective thresholds we're testing) to ensure our application rate stays within our desired range (50% - 75%). Then for each set of thresholds which produce an application rate within our desired range we would want to store only the set of which maximizes accuracy, along with their respective location id, application rate, and accuracy rate. The desired output is listed below.

```
      location act_1_thresh act_2_thresh application_rate accuracy_rate
1        1           13           19             0.52          0.45
2        2           11           24             0.57          0.53
3        3           14           21             0.67          0.42
```

I had tried writing this into a for loop, but was not able to navigate my way through the number of nested arguments I would have to make in order to account for all of these conditions. I would appreciate assistance from anyone who has attempted a similar problem. Thank you!

An example of how to calculate the application and accuracy rate for a single set of thresholds is listed below.

```
### Create yard IDs
location <- c(1,2,3)

### Create a single set of thresholds
single_act_1_threshold <- 12
single_act_2_threshold <- 20

### Calculate the simulated application, and success rate of thresholds mentioned above using historical data
as.data.table(testFile)[,
                        list(
                        application_rate = round(sum(ifelse(single_act_1_threshold <= activity1 | single_act_2_threshold <= activity2, 1, 0))/
                                                   nrow(testFile),2),
                        accuracy_rate = round(sum(ifelse((single_act_1_threshold <= activity1 | single_act_2_threshold <= activity2) & (outcome == 1), 1, 0))/
                                                sum(ifelse(single_act_1_threshold <= activity1 | single_act_2_threshold <= activity2, 1, 0)),2)
                        ),
                        by = location]
```

Comment: What is `location` in your sample data (i.e, `rep.int(location, 20)`)? Also, please show (not tell in words) the code to calculate your thresholds and rates with **one** location ID so we can help extend to all IDs.

Comment: Please see the adjusted instructions and script above. Please note this only shows the calculation of the application and accuracy rate for a single set of thresholds. I would like to be able to iterate over unique combinations of two sets of thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `expand.grid` that builds a data frame of all combinations betwen both thresholds. Then use `Map` to iterate elementwise between both columns of data frame to build a list of data tables (of which now includes columns for each threshold indicator).

```
act_1_thresholds <- seq(7,12,1)
act_2_thresholds <- seq(19,24,1)

# ALL COMBINATIONS
thresholds_df <- expand.grid(th1=act_1_thresholds, th2=act_2_thresholds)

# USER-DEFINED FUNCTION
calc <- function(th1, th2)
     as.data.table(testFile)[, list(
                                  act_1_thresholds = th1,     # NEW COLUMN
                                  act_2_thresholds = th2,     # NEW COLUMN                      
                                  application_rate = round(sum(ifelse(th1 <= activity1 | th2 <= activity2, 1, 0)) /
                                                           nrow(testFile),2),
                                  accuracy_rate = round(sum(ifelse((th1 <= activity1 | th2 <= activity2) & (outcome == 1), 1, 0)) /
                                                        sum(ifelse(th1 <= activity1 | th2 <= activity2, 1, 0)),2)
                                ), by = location]    
# LIST OF DATA TABLES
dt_list <- Map(calc, thresholds_df$th1, thresholds_df$th2)

# NAME ELEMENTS OF LIST
names(dt_list) <- paste(thresholds_df$th1, thresholds_df$th2, sep="_")

# SAME RESULT AS POSTED EXAMPLE
dt_list$`12_20`  
#    location act_1_thresholds act_2_thresholds application_rate accuracy_rate
# 1:        1               12               20             0.23           0.5
# 2:        2               12               20             0.23           0.5
# 3:        3               12               20             0.23           0.5
```

And if you need to append all elements use data.table's `rbindlist`:

```
final_dt <- rbindlist(dt_list)
final_dt

#      location act_1_thresholds act_2_thresholds application_rate accuracy_rate
#   1:        1                7               19             0.32          0.47
#   2:        2                7               19             0.32          0.47
#   3:        3                7               19             0.32          0.47
#   4:        1                8               19             0.32          0.47
#   5:        2                8               19             0.32          0.47
#  ---                                                                          
# 104:        2               11               24             0.20          0.42
# 105:        3               11               24             0.20          0.42
# 106:        1               12               24             0.15          0.56
# 107:        2               12               24             0.15          0.56
# 108:        3               12               24             0.15          0.56
```